# Copying a MySQL database with all data, from one computer to another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, data-migration

I got a new laptop and want to move my entire development environment, as is, to my new machine

Everything was incredibly easy, except for the MySQL database, which is turning out to be a complete nightmare. Eventually, I copied it to my new machine and got it set up, using the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -p tillyoudrop_dev > tillyoudrop_dev.sql

mysql -u root -p tillyoudrop_dev < tillyoudrop.sql
```

But when I enter the rails console, I find that only the tables seem to have copied, but no data...

For example , when I enter `User` I get

```
2.0.0-p451 :003 > User
 => User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, cart_id: integer, superadmin: boolean, invitation_token: string, invitation_sent_at: datetime, invitation_accepted_at: datetime, invitation_limit: integer, invited_by_id: integer, invited_by_type: string) 
2.0.0-p451 :004 >
```

which is the desired, correct behaviour, but when I look for entries:

```
2.0.0-p451 :004 > User.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` 
 => 0 
2.0.0-p451 :005 >
```

There are none. How do I copy the actual data from my old dev environment to my new one?

Comment: When you look in the sql file do you actually see the data?

Comment: Yes I do. Here is an example:
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (5,'info@dearrae.co.za','$2a$10$mz5YC.Rqp9HMf2KWWSY9QeJMrQI81lLXhMzPkkEzJS3ecsRLE9Fgy',NULL,NULL,'2013-10-17 10:22:00',44,'2013-10-29 09:23:21','2013-10-29 08:27:22','105.237.17.170','105.237.17.170','2013-07-30 14:13:57','2013-10-29 09:23:21',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),(6,'dianegush@gmail.com','$2a$10$eukJZMxjRJZFcsk.ruPNHeapRZRQ082wtCgug1xeRnuKNMGYz5ScO',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2013-07-30 15:28:53','2013-07-30 15:28:53','196.215.97.51','196.215.97.51','2013-07-30 14:13:57','2013-07-30 15:28:53',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL ...

Comment: And if you go into `mysql` directly, and do `select count(*) from users` do you see the data?  Also, can you run your application on your new machine?

Comment: It seems I have two databases in here: `test` and `information_schema`. Information schema says `ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'users' in information_schema` and test says `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.users' doesn't exist`

Comment: I think you forgot to go into mysql and `create database tillyoudrop_dev` before you try to import the schema and data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did that.
I just checked my working database on my old machine and the normal sql gives the same behaviour on there. with information_schema and test

Comment: `mysql -u root -p tillyoudrop_dev` to call up mysql and actually go into that database.

Comment: Okay I've just done that. When I `select count (*) from users` it shows a table with count(*) and 0. and it says `1 row in set`

Comment: And when doing this on the old machine it says 180 instead of 0

Comment: While you are still in mysql, try `\. tillyoudrop_dev.sql` and see if it can load in the database.  *** DON'T DO THAT ON YOUR OLD MACHINE THOUGH... ;- ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading the data directly from the command line, import the file from within mysql itself:

`$ mysql -u root -p tillyoudrop_dev`

`mysql> \. tillyoudrop_dev.sql`